# How to edit/remove any elements from online page then save edited page in same look with html css and images and PDF?

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, internet-explorer, html

How to remove any elements from online page, and then save edited page in same look with HTML, CSS and images?

I also need to edit text.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [The Printliminator](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ThePrintliminator/) bookmarklet is all you need? I've never tested it for saving the results though.

As you also commented you want to edit text: add-ons like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or the built-in Web Inspector in Safari and Chrome do allow for [editing on the fly](http://getfirebug.com/html.html). But it's a but tedious. Save before you start.

And when saving before you start then maybe using some HTML editor is much easier?

(For saving, I guess you can use the built-in Save function from your browser, which often has an option to save the complete page. Hopefully that will save the edited version then.)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that for Firefox, the [Aardvark](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4111) add-on is a solution:

> Powerful and user-friendly selector
>   utility for selecting elements and
>   doing various actions on them. It can
>   be used for cleaning up a page prior
>   to printing it (by removing and
>   isolating elements), for making the
>   page more readable, and (most
>   appreciated by web developers), for
>   analyzing the structure of a page.

Comment: but i need editing also . i mean editing of text

Comment: @Jitendra, as for editing: your question also has an edit option. :-) (I've merged your extra requirement into that question.)

Comment: @Jitendra: You're better off in this case to save the page after Aardvark and finish the editing using whatever tool you have (even notepad).